# The behaviour of the chatterjee correlation coefficient with binary data

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, chatterjee-xicor

Using the house price data from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction) and `xicorpy`, I have done some experimentation about how Chatterjee correlation coefficients behave in comparison to Pearson.

Since Chatterjee's coefficient is a non-symmetric measurement of correlation power and ranges from 0 to 1, I have taken absolute value of the pearson coefficient and the lowest Xi value for the {x,y} pairs for comparison.

[image: matrices]

As you can see from the plot above, they broadly select the same variables as significantly correlated. However, Xi seems to pick out false correlations with binary/discrete variables, most notably {waterfront, yr_renovated}.

[image: false correlation]

So my question is: why does the chatterjee coefficient Xi preferably pick out correlations with binary variables? Am I missing something?

code for the taking the minimum chatterjee xi:

```
from functools import wraps

@wraps(compute_xi_correlation)
def symmetric_xi(x, y=None, *args, **kwargs):
    xis = compute_xi_correlation(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
    xis[:] = np.where(np.abs(xis) < np.abs(xis.T), xis, xis.T)
    return xis
```

For a better example:

```
n = 10000
us = np.random.uniform(0, 1., n//2)
x, y = np.linspace(0, 1, n), np.append(np.zeros(n//2)+us, np.ones(n//2)-us)
y = np.where(y>0.5, 1, 0)

from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
window = 1000
sliding = sliding_window_view(y, window_shape=window).mean(axis=1)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x[window-1:], sliding, '-')
xicorpy.compute_xi_correlation(x, y)
```

This gives us a coefficient of 0.25 when it should be near 0.

Comment: With binary data, you have a lot of ties. The R implementation of *xicor* by Chatterjee himself has a parameter *TIES*. Have you tried setting it to *true*? Nevertheless the question remains how Chatterjee's correlation performs when the data consist almost exclusively of ties (for binary data, at least half of the data must be ties, in practical cases usally much more).